# How to store Bootstrap Rows and Coloumns in a database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have implemented a grid system in HTML and bootstrap. These grid contains of panels and they carry various information.I have made these panel movable(drag, drop) using jQuery and some custom java-script and bootstrap.

I need to store the position where each and every item after exiting the session(log out)

Here is my code

```
<div class="container sortable">
        <div class="row"><!-- BEGIN ROW -->             
        <div class="col-md-4 placeholder-wrapper">
            <div class="panel panel-default" id="portlet-linear-color">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="panel-title">
                        Portlet 1
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-controls">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a class=
                                "portlet-collapse portlet-icon portlet-icon-collapse"
                                data-toggle="collapse" href="#" style=
                                "font-style: italic"></a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class=
                                "portlet-refresh portlet-icon portlet-icon-refresh"
                                data-toggle="refresh" href="#" style=
                                "font-style: italic"></a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class=
                                "portlet-close portlet-icon portlet-icon-close"
                                data-toggle="close" href="#" style=
                                "font-style: italic"></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <h3><span class="semi-bold">Linear</span> Progress</h3>
                    <p>Click on the refresh icon to simulate an AJAX call and to see an
                    animated progress bar indicator above the portlet. These progress
                    bars come in seven different colors that are available in the Pages
                    contextual color scheme.</p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 placeholder-wrapper">
            <div class="panel panel-default" id="portlet-linear-color">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="panel-title">
                        Portlet 2
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-controls">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a class=
                                "portlet-collapse portlet-icon portlet-icon-collapse"
                                data-toggle="collapse" href="#" style=
                                "font-style: italic"></a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class=
                                "portlet-refresh portlet-icon portlet-icon-refresh"
                                data-toggle="refresh" href="#" style=
                                "font-style: italic"></a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class=
                                "portlet-close portlet-icon portlet-icon-close"
                                data-toggle="close" href="#" style=
                                "font-style: italic"></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <h3><span class="semi-bold">Linear</span> Progress</h3>
                    <p>Click on the refresh icon to simulate an AJAX call and to see an
                    animated progress bar indicator above the portlet. These progress
                    bars come in seven different colors that are available in the Pages
                    contextual color scheme.</p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 placeholder-wrapper">
            <div class="panel panel-default" id="portlet-linear-color">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="panel-title">
                        Portlet 3
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-controls">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a class=
                                "portlet-collapse portlet-icon portlet-icon-collapse"
                                data-toggle="collapse" href="#" style=
                                "font-style: italic"></a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class=
                                "portlet-refresh portlet-icon portlet-icon-refresh"
                                data-toggle="refresh" href="#" style=
                                "font-style: italic"></a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class=
                                "portlet-close portlet-icon portlet-icon-close"
                                data-toggle="close" href="#" style=
                                "font-style: italic"></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <h3><span class="semi-bold">Linear</span> Progress</h3>
                    <p>Click on the refresh icon to simulate an AJAX call and to see an
                    animated progress bar indicator above the portlet. These progress
                    bars come in seven different colors that are available in the Pages
                    contextual color scheme.</p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        </div><!-- END ROW -->    
        <div class="row"><!-- BEGIN ROW 1 -->
            <div class="col-md-4 placeholder-wrapper"><!-- BEGIN WRAPPER -->
                <div class="panel panel-default" id="portlet-linear-color"><!-- BEGIN PANEL -->
                    <div class="panel-heading"><!-- BEGIN HEADER -->
                        <div class="panel-title">
                            Portlet 4
                        </div>
                            <div class="panel-controls"><!-- BEGIN  ICONS -->
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <a class=
                                        "portlet-collapse portlet-icon portlet-icon-collapse"
                                        data-toggle="collapse" href="#" style=
                                        "font-style: italic"></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a class=
                                        "portlet-refresh portlet-icon portlet-icon-refresh"
                                        data-toggle="refresh" href="#" style=
                                        "font-style: italic"></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a class=
                                        "portlet-close portlet-icon portlet-icon-close"
                                        data-toggle="close" href="#" style=
                                        "font-style: italic"></a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div><!-- END ICONS -->
                    </div><!-- END HEADER -->
                <div class="panel-body"><!-- BEGIN PANEL CONTENT -->
                    <h3><span class="semi-bold">Linear</span> Progress</h3>
                    <p>Click on the refresh icon to simulate an AJAX call and to see an
                    animated progress bar indicator above the portlet. These progress
                    bars come in seven different colors that are available in the Pages
                    contextual color scheme.</p>
                </div><!-- END PANEL CONTENT -->
            </div><!-- END PANEL -->

        </div><!-- END WRAPPER -->
        </div><!-- END ROW 2 -->
    </div>
```

Is there anyway I can save these instances in a database ?

Comment: Yes, POST them using AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the current html of a page use JQuery.
This will work.

```
     <script>
        var contentData = $('#divwithhtml').html();
        //If you want to post it
        $.post( "yoururl.php", { content: "contentData " })
      .done(function( data ) {
        alert( "Data Loaded: " + data + " posted html succesfull");
      });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer i tried your way and the code works
How do you save it in a database 
like a String or is there any other format ?

I saved it as a String but how can i echo it out as HTML elements and content ?

Comment: If you want to get a full html page you use .html() If you want to store it you can use either html() or .text(). text will get all the html and converts it into a string. If you want to echo or display it from the database just do echo $yourhtml;

Answer (score 0):

I think you can save base layout in database . then each client reposition each site item then you should save position in database by ajax for clientId .

> Edited Post:

It's very simple you can echo string code like this :

```
select `columnName` from `database` where `clientId`=20
```

when fetch this return query and save to $row you can try this :

```
echo $row["columnName"];
```

OR

```
$ret="<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
         <title>site name</title>
    </head>
    <body>
         {$row["columnName"]}
    </body>
</html>";

echo $ret;
```

Comment: How do you save it in a database 
like a String or is there any other format ?

I saved it as a String but how can i echo it out as HTML elements and content ?